# How to load XML file when created setup file in c#.net

Tags: c#, xml

I have already created setup files but xml files are not loading. 
I have kept all XML files in an a support folder.
Please help me identify the causes behind the issue.
Kindly let me know, what setup details do I need to check/ what more information do I need to provide?

Comment: Show us the code and describe better your problem, with such a poor description none will be able to help.

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: I want to save some information ,so i added xml file in my c# project ,which keep record data ,it work properly when run the project to visual stdio but when create setup file and setup, then click to run but it not work,i am sure that it can not load file.xml